# This has been a timely reminder to us all. (has been vs. is)

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

> This has been a timely reminder to us all.

vs.

> This is a timely reminder to us all.

What's the difference between 'has been' vs. 'is'?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence uses the **present perfect** tense to say something started in the past and continues in the present.

> This has been a timely reminder to us all.

might continue...

> We are now repairing the
> town's defences.

The second sentence uses the **simple present** tense. The reminder is new or recent:

> This is a timely reminder to us all.

might continue...

> We should/must/will now repair the
> town's defences.